# C# Desktop app Authentication for Confluence or Jira?

Tags: c#, .net, kerberos, confluence-rest-api, sspi

I am creating a desktop application where I want to retrieve some pages or information from Confluence and Jira and maybe other tools.

I'm using RestSharp to make the API Request, but my question is if I need to make some kind of authentication for the user if he is already logged in with his user and psw into SAP/Kerberos. I see some people use SSPI?

At the moment I can retrieve data from other rest api but not confluence or jira so I am thinking maybe authentication is the problem.

So what would be a good way to go about this? User logins into windows (same login credentials for windows, confluence, jira etc) and with the desktop app he can retrieve/manipulate information from confluence/jira with his account.

Thank you!

Edit1:
Here is how I am trying to retrieve now a page:

```
public class GetApix
{
    public static string getxxx(string url)
    {
        string info = null;
        var credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        var options = new RestClientOptions(url)
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = credentials
        };
        var client = new RestClient(options);

        var request = new RestRequest();
        var response = client.Get(request);

        info = response.Content.ToString();

        return info;
    }
}
```

Call the function:

```
public string xxx => GetApix.getxxx("https://confluence.xxx.yyy.cloud/api/MyPage");
```

I have tried different urls type (rest/api, api/) but still does not work.

In Postman I can get the response without auth just by using the url without any rest or api tags

Comment: The three platforms of Confluence & Jira (Cloud, Data Center, and Server) have different ways to handle single sign-on. Which of those—Cloud, Data Center, or Server—are you trying to solve this for?

Comment: If possible all of them at once. The user has the same credentials for all of them, and once he is logged in Windows, he also is logged in all the other tools. So in my desktop app I'm looking for some "DefaultCredentials"  for each user to use. (each user has their own credential)

Comment: "If possible all of them at once" @Lodes Even if you'd like to support all of Confluence Cloud, Confluence Data Center, and Confluence Server it sounds like you are testing with a specific one of those so it would help to know which one.

Comment: right now I am trying to retrieve data from a page in Confluence Cloud